# authentication on webserver

Tags: php, python, django, web-frameworks

on my beaglebone i have installed hostapd, iscdhcp and lighttpd so i can build a router and webserver.
let say my network is not secured so every on can be connected to it, and will get an ip-address from the beaglebone-server.

After the person is connected to the network and he starts a browser he should be redirected to a homepage to give his password, if he is not authenticated yet.

do i need a webframe-work (like django) for this purpose?? if not what else??
i am familiar with programming in python, php, html and java.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of these framework since the have authetications nativly implemented but you don't need to, you can build your own authentication system: You will need a database/file to store credentails and a authentication program verifying credentials against this given storage in any language your webserver can use.

However I would strongly recommend you to use an established framework for authetication.